# Invalid provider for the NgModule 'DynamicTestModule' when testing a service in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, testing, angular-services

I have the following service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { MenuItem } from './../classes/menu-item';
import { ITEMS } from './../static-data/items-list';

@Injectable()
export class ItemsListService {

    getItems(): Promise<MenuItem[]> {
        return Promise.resolve(ITEMS);
    }

}
```

The test for this service is here:

```
import { TestBed, async, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { ItemListService } from './item-list.service';
import { MenuItem } from './../classes/menu-item';
import { ITEMS } from './../static-data/items-list';

describe('ItemListService', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        providers: [ ItemListService, MenuItem, ITEMS ]
    });
  });

  it('should ...', inject([ItemListService], (service: ItemListService) => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  }));
});
```

The MenuItem is defined here:

```
export class MenuItem {
    name: string;
    link: string;
}
```

ITEMS is defined here:
import { MenuItem } from './../classes/menu-item';

```
export var ITEMS: MenuItem[] = [
    {name: 'Vehicles', link: '/vehicles'},
    {name: 'Gateways', link: '/gateways'},
    {name: 'Statuses', link: '/statuses'},
    {name: 'Logs', link: '/logs'}
]
```

When I run the test I am getting in the browsers console the followings errors:

```
FAILED ItemListService should ...
```

and

[image]

So why do I have these errors? And what is the solution for the test to work?

Comment: Do you have any dependency in ItemListService ?

Comment: No I don't have, but I found the issue. Check out the answer I have made.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

This is such an annoying error, thought I'd include another subtle cause to look for in your spec. In my case I specified `providers` **instead of the correct value of `provide`** as below

```
 TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [{provider: ApplicationActions, useClass: ActionMock}]
```

rather than offer useful information like "no 'provide' key specified" it simply reports

> Failed: Invalid provider for the NgModule 'DynamicTestModule' - only
> instances of Provider and Type are allowed, got: [?[object Object]?,
> ...]

Comment: and Check spelling and capitalization explicitly.  When I was looking into this issue, it was because I used a capital letter instead of lowercase.  `Provide` as opposed to `provide`

Comment: Nice catch, just for being explicit I add the correct syntax: `providers: [{provide: ApplicationActions, useClass: ActionMock}]` or `providers: [{provide: ApplicationActions, useValue: actionMockInstance}]`

Comment: It's `provide` not `provider`

Comment: I had this error because of an extra comma.

Answer (score 2):

BTW also mind to use the class in providers, not some variable. This happened to me due to an accidental problematic replacement/casing:

#### Correct

```
 TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    // ...
    providers: [ SomeService ]
}
```

instead of...

#### Incorrect

```
 TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    // ...
    providers: [ someService ]
}
```

Note the camelCase variable (`someService`) is likely there if you use it in your test, that's why it does not throw a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had a stray comma in one of my provider lines, causing the `DynamicTestModule` to think I had passed an `undefined` definition.

```
        {
          provide: ApiService,
          useValue: {
            getUsers: jasmine
              .createSpy('getUsers')
              .and.returnValue(of({ status: 200, body: [] })),
          },
        },
        , // whoops!
        MessageService,
        { provide: Location, useValue: { back: jasmine.createSpy('back') } },
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error, because of an extra comma in the providers array.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of camelCase inside providers [..] array.

Correct way:

```
beforeEach(() => {
        providers: [TestService, ...]
    }
);
```

Answer (score -2):

I have same problem, when importing in my `Ionic Framework` project like this:

```
import {Device} from '@ionic-native/device'
```

instead of:

```
import {Device} from '@ionic-native/device/ngx'
```

Comment: This response is not useful.